# RMI - java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost , while using System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", IP)

Tags: java, rmi

I have two servers that communicate to each other via RMI. I'm trying to test then on localhost but this error is thrown.

I tried to use `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", IP);` and `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","localhost");` but I still get this error.

I don't have idea why this happens to these servers, because I have others servers that comunicate via RMI to the ProxyServer or to the DatanodeServer and this error isn't thrown.

ProxyServer.java

```
public class ProxyServer implements Proxy {

private static int port = 7001;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String IP = localIP();
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", IP);

        ProxyServer obj = new ProxyServer();
        Proxy stub = (Proxy) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, port);   

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        registry.bind("Proxy", stub);

        System.out.println("Server ready!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void create(String file, String text) {
    try {                       
        Registry namenodeRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", NamenodeServer.getPort());
        Namenode namenodeStub = (Namenode) namenodeRegistry.lookup("Namenode");
        namenodeStub.addFile(file);
        int id = getDatanodeID(file);           
        Registry datanodeRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 5000 + id);
        Datanode datanodeStub = (Datanode) datanodeRegistry.lookup("Datanode" + String.valueOf(id));
        datanodeStub.create(file, text);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
// other methods
```

DatanodeServer.java

```
public class DatanodeServer implements Datanode {
private int port;
private int id;

public DatanodeServer(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.port = 5000 + id;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Datanode id: ");
    int id = sc.nextInt();

    try {           
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.168.1.2");

        DatanodeServer obj = new DatanodeServer(id);
        Datanode stub = (Datanode) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, obj.getPort());

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(obj.getPort());
        registry.rebind("Datanode" + String.valueOf(id), stub);

        System.out.println("Servidor pronto!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Create file
@Override
public void create(String fileName, String text) {
    Path file = Paths.get("datanode" + String.valueOf(this.id) + "/" + fileName); // Converte uma String em um Path
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, charset, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {
        writer.write(text, 0, text.length()); 
        Registry proxyRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", ProxyServer.getPort());
        Proxy proxyStub = (Proxy) proxyRegistry.lookup("Proxy");
        proxyStub.sendToClient("Arquivo " + fileName + ".txt criado!");
        } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
// other methods
```

Error at at proxy.ProxyServer.create - 65: Datanode datanodeStub = (Datanode) datanodeRegistry.lookup("Datanode" + String.valueOf(id));

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:338)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:112)
    at proxy.ProxyServer.create(ProxyServer.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the result of `createRegistry()` in a static variable. Otherwise it can be garbage-collected.

Comment: There was no problem with rmi, the problem was with the method to get the datanode id, so the proxy was trying to find the registry at the wrong port. I'm probably gonna delete this question